# UITableView within a UINavigationController within a UITabBarController, unwanted bottom toolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I'm having trouble with this hierarchy producing an unwanted empty UIToolbar directly above my TabBar.

[image]

I've tried using the inspector in XCode to figure out where it's coming from but the view heirarchy is not clear about what this toolbar is nested within. This seems like it would be a common problem but I'm not having any luck searching for solutions.

Comment: Oh jeez. A stale `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO];` was in my component and apparently had no effect until I restructured the container components to utilize a UITabBarController. Can I delete my post since it's not helpful and makes me look like an idiot?

Answer (score 2):

Check your storyboard in the interface builder, under the Attributes Inspector > Simulated Metrics > Bottom Bar. Without knowing more about your project, it should be set to "inferred" (as in, inferred from the Tab Bar navigation controller).

Comment: I actually set it to "None" on both the navigation controller and table view controller. I set it back to "Inferred", but there was no change in the appearance.